# Fetching contact from Contact list in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-contacts

```
public class PhoneActivity extends Activity
{
private static final String TAG = PhoneActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS = 1;
private Uri uriContact;
private String contactID;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

 public void onClickSelectContact(View btnSelectContact) {
   startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI),REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS); 
   }

  @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

      if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          Log.d(TAG,"Response:" + data.toString());  
          uriContact = data.getData();

          retrieveContactName();
      retrieveContactNumber();
          retrieveContactPhoto();
        }
     }

   private void retrieveContactPhoto() {
        Bitmap photo = null;

         try
             {
               InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                          ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,new Long(contactID)));

                   if(inputStream != null) {
                    photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    }
              assert inputStream != null;
              inputStream.close();

             }  catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 } 
               }

    private void retrieveContactNumber()  {
           String contactNumber = null;

          Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
                                   new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
                                   null,null,null);
          if(cursorID.moveToFirst()) {
             contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            }
             cursorID.close();
             Log.d(TAG,"Contact ID:" + contactID);

              Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

                              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + "=" +
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE, 
                                new String[]{contactID},null);

        if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
           contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
         }

    cursorPhone.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact Phone Number: " + contactNumber);
} 
      private void retrieveContactName() {
             String contactName = null;
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriContact, null, null, null,null);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
          }
           cursor.close();
         Log.d(TAG, "Contact Name : " + contactName);             
       }
```

> App Getting Crashed when i select contact in contacts.Problem is in          returning result to Activity called.I have Posted logcat

```
06-08 13:16:06.488  1520  1520 D PhoneActivity: Contact Name : Jeevankumar M
 06-08 13:16:06.515  1520  1520 D PhoneActivity: Contact ID:1
 06-08 13:16:06.554  1520  1520 D PhoneActivity: Contact Phone Number: (974) 303-3493
 06-08 13:16:06.575  1272  1272 I Choreographer: Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 06-08 13:16:06.721  1520  1520 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.phone, PID: 1520
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r1-3B31315329433D5141294B41/1 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.phone/com.example.phone.PhoneActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference
 06-08 13:16:06.731  1520  1520 E AndroidRuntime:   at com.example.phone.PhoneActivity.retrieveContactPhoto(PhoneActivity.java:67
```

> Referred Link from Github : https://gist.github.com/evandrix/7058235
>        
>         **can anyone help pls? Thanks in Advance..**

Comment: Don't do this work on the main thread. Use different thread. Make some use of Async Task.

Comment: @ShubhamChauhan i think Async Task is not necessary for just picking a contact..problem is  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think error is here :

```
try
             {
               InputStream inputStream = ...

                    }
              assert inputStream != null; // here
              inputStream.close();

             }  catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 } 
               }
```

Try to declare `InputStream inputStream;` before oncreate() with all other variables.

Comment: @user3357003 First of all make use of AsyncTask. You are making UI thread heavy and may be because of this you are not getting any values. App is skipping your operations.

Comment: @user3357003 see this line Choreographer: Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code

```
private void readContacts() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("......Contact Details.....");
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    String phone = null;
    String emailContact = null;
    String emailType = null;
    String image_uri = "";
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                try {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    image_uri = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
                    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                                sb.append("\n Contact Name:" + name);



                        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                            phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            int type = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                            int label = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(Phone.LABEL));


                            String type_new = (String) Phone.getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, "");
                            String label_new = (String) Phone.getTypeLabel(getResources(), label, "");



                            sb.append("\n Phone number:" + phone);
                        }
                        pCur.close();
                        Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                        while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                            emailContact = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                            emailType = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                            sb.append("\nEmail:" + emailContact + "Email type:" + emailType);
                                }
                        emailCur.close();

                        String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                        String[] orgWhereParams = new String[] { id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
                        Cursor orgCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);
                        if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) {
                            String orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA));
                            String title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));




                        }
                        orgCur.close();


                    }
                    if (image_uri != null) {
                        // System.out.println(Uri.parse(image_uri));
                        try {
                            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(image_uri));
                            sb.append("\n Image in Bitmap:" + bitmap);
                            // System.out.println(bitmap);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    sb.append("\n........................................");
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }

            }
            }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

}
```